# Паттерн Memento в java

Tags: java

Такой нубовский вопрос. С помощью паттерна Memento (знаю что устарел но так по заданию) сделать так, чтоб при выходе из графического редактора, нарисованное в нем сохранялось, и при следующем запуске редактор будет в том состоянии что и до выхода. Я не могу понять, вот например с помощью этого паттерна сделать функции "вперед", "назад" можно, так как они в рамках одной сессии, а вот если мы закрываем приложение, то сессия обрывается и данные удаляются.Я так понимаю нужно реализовать хранилище куда эти данные будут записываться, и при включении прогграммы подставляться в нее? Возможно ли сделать это без сериализации?

Comment: Нет, без сериализации это сделать нельзя.

Comment: Ты хочешь сохранять действия, но не использовать сериализацию (превращение действий в записываемый набор данных). Не получится на 2 стула сесть. А что если кто-то отредактирует картинку между запусками? Что именно ты будешь отменять? Думаю из-за этой проблемы  подобноно функционала не существует.